# Which method is less error prone?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I completed the following work recently using two methods.  The first you can see on the left hand side, doing all working with the original measurements.

In the second method, which you can see on the right, I’ve done the same process but shifted the decimal place on all original measurement and just recorded the result.  At the end I left-shift the answer by 1e-4 to arrive at the correct answer.

Which is the “better” as in less error prone method to use?

- Doing all calculations with the original decimal values and then inflating and simplifying, or;
- Creating integers, calculating and then re-adjusting

I’m trying to teach myself mathematics here and don’t have a teacher or other students to bounce this off of and would appreciate any input.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always best to work with integers  unless you are working with "display digits" where numbers are processed a digit at a time the way humans do arithmetic.

The reason is, for example,
$\quad 0.3_2 = 0.01001100110011\cdots\quad $ and is never exact. You can do little about the initial presentation but, any operations done on decimal fractions in a binary environment will only compound the error.
When possible, it is good to do all calculations with rational numbers like keeping $\dfrac{14}{15}$ the away you would with an algebraic $\dfrac{A}{B}$ rather than converting to  $0.933333333333333\cdots$ because no amount of multiplication can convert "that" to an integer. It is possible to multiply $14\times 15=210$ and process with "that" integer as long as you remember to divide by $15$ at the end.

In a binary world, $\space base_{10}$ integers are better than decimals and in a decimal world, ratioal numbers are better than having digits to the right of the "decimal point."

Comment: Thanks Poetasis!